# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' why i am getting this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 showSecret = false;

logArray = [];

onToggleDetails()
{
this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
this.logArray.push(this.logArray.length);
}

}
```

while running the above code , Angular is giving below error
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:16:20 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

**this.logArray.push(this.logArray.length);**

Answer (score 5):

The compiler wants you to declare the type of your logArray. Try following:

```
logArray: number[] = [];
```

Let me know if it works:)